# How does Windows detect if a program is "stopped working"?

Tags: windows, crash, windows-error-reporting

When I clicked the X button to close a program (say it is MYAPP), a dialog popped up saying:

> MYAPP has stopped working
>
> Windows can check online for a solution to the problem."

But actually the application had already exited.

Error info:

```
    Problem signature:
      Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
      Application Name: MYAPP.EXE
      Application Version:  1.0.0.0
      Application Timestamp:    56a8dfa8
      Fault Module Name:    MSVCP90D.dll
      Fault Module Version: 9.0.30729.6161
      Fault Module Timestamp:   4dace5bf
      Exception Code:   c0000005
      Exception Offset: 00007b3f
      OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
      Locale ID:    3081
```

How does Windows detect if a program is "stopped working"? Does it indicate the application throws an exception or a dead lock?

Comment: Well, in that particular case the cause is straightforward: exception 0xc0000005, which is a memory access violation.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Is there a way to let the program break at the memory access violation point and launch Visual Studio?

Comment: If Visual Studio is installed, Windows will usually offer to debug the program.  But if that isn't working for some reason, you could explicitly run it in the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Error Reporting (WER) will catch unhandled exceptions. It won't catch a deadlock. That dialog box that pops up when a program "stops working" is a WER crash-dump being taken (or it communicating with a MS server to see if it wants to take a crash-dump, etc.).

There are several ways to debug a crashing program that are tried and true (although arduous). Some of these include:

- Using GFlags to launch Visual Studio or WinDbg
- Including code in the program to launch a debugger

In this case with WER, you could turn on local crash dumps, and then, as long as you have the symbol database (pdb) file, you can debug from a local crash dump. You can read more on taking local crash dumps at [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx).